# How JS object literals or arrays determine whether to create certain attributes based on judgment

Tags: javascript

My expression may not be clear, Is the following code abbreviated

```js
let a = true;
let obj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
if(a){
  obj.z = 3
}
```

or

```js
let a = true;
let arr = ['a', 'b'];
if(a){
  arr.push('c')
}
arr = arr.concat('d','e')
```

Maybe I am too lazy, but I still want to ask, I don’t know how to search for this problem on Google.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Your code is right, what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Objects

You can't (reasonably) optionally create an object property in an object initializer based on a flag. The way you have it in your first example is how you'd do that.

The unreasonable way is with spread notation (ES2018+ for objects) and the conditional operator:

```
let obj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  ...(a ? {z: 3} : {})
};
```

Example:

```js
let a = true;
let obj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  ...(a ? {z: 3} : {})
};
console.log(obj);
```

If you can't rely on object spread (it is quite new), you'd use `Object.assign` instead (again, if we're being unreasonable :-) ):

```
let obj = Object.assign({
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}, a ? {z: 3} : null);
```

Example:

```js
let a = true;
let obj = Object.assign({
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}, a ? {z: 3} : null);
console.log(obj);
```

#### Arrays

You can't (reasonably) optionally create an entry in an array initializer based on a flag. You'd want to do it as you've shown.

As with objects, the unreasonable way is with spread notation (ES2015+ for arrays) and the conditional operator:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', ...(a ? ['c'] : []), 'd', 'e'];
```

Example:

```js
let a = true;
let arr = ['a', 'b', ...(a ? ['c'] : []), 'd', 'e'];
console.log(arr);
```